# How to specify a return path in Azure Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook

I want to import >1100 seismic time series files from Azure into a Azure online hosted Notebook for processing. My code currently copies the file directly into my project source directory instead of neatly into my "../data/" directory.

I can import things from all over the project using the "~/library/../" string. However, the same trick isn't working when I try to direct the data where to go.

I did some research online but most results don't seem to cover this particular use case. I've tried many variations of file paths but to no avail.

How can I write files to a directory relative to my home path?

```
import_path = "~/library/04_processedData/seismicflatfile.csv" 
return_path = "RSN1100_KOBE_ABN-UP.csv"
blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name, "RSN1100_KOBE_ABN-UP.DT2", return_path)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the local path with,

```
local_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
if not os.path.isfile(local_path):
        blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME, blob_name, local_path)
```

Refer the [`sample here`](https://github.com/EdmundTse/data-512-project/blob/0f010dd244c897a99582d2df340956f134dafeaf/project.ipynb)

Comment: Finally got it to work with some additional help from `os.getcwd()`